# Partner Business org for Salesforce Checkmarx review?

Tags: apex, managed-package, lightning-apps, appexchange

I have developed a **2nd generation Managed package** for Salesforce App Exchange. I want to submit my Scratch Org Code for Salesforce Checkmarx security check.

Can any one suggest how to get my code security check reviewed?

OR

For Partner Business Org, Which type of org we need to connect for Salesforce Checkmarx review -

1. Scratch Org (Where development is done)
2. Dev Hub Org
3. Git Environment (Where code is present)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you need the org to be available for more than 30 days, you cannot use a scratch org. You need to set up a dev org instead, where you should install the package (not deploy the code). Have you been through the [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/isv_security_review) and read the [ISVForce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_guidelines.htm)?

Comment: For partners, using the partner security scanner portal, you get to select the package and version to submit to Checkmarx without using any org at all.

Comment: @PhilW , currently we haven't created a released version of the managed package. Currently we are testing only on the Beta package and it is stable now. Now as a next step we need to generate a CheckMarx report which needs to be done by submitting the org with Checkmarx for CRUD/FLS/Quality(for listing this app on appexchange). It was easy in first generation but in Second Generation how can we submit for checkmarx review.

Comment: @PhilW Should we create the first release version of the managed package and then connect the Dev Hub Org with the Partner Account and then in the partner account we will see an option to submit the dev Hub account/selected managed package(released version) for checkmarx review or is there a way in which we can submit the the Beta package for checkmarx review also from the Partner Account as our limit for 360000 lines is already exhausted. 
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: As a partner you must use your PBO as the Dev Hub; this was mandated by Salesforce (we didn't want to do this, but that was the only choice if we wanted the high scratch org management limits). That means the package is correctly associated with your partner account. Whether you need to create a managed release before you can Checkmarx for the first time, I don't know - we had already created managed releases before we went to security review. You can definitely scan beta releases.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for response,
But I think My question is still open. 
I have developed beta version managed package and I want to get Checkmarx security checked for this beta package.
But I don't know how to get my Scratch org security checked. All the development is done in this Scratch Org.
Can you just me something in this direction?

Comment: The scratch org is irrelevant for the Checkmarx submission. I believe what's important is having the package created in your Dev Hub and your Dev Hub being on your PBO. You then need to login to the [partner security portal](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/) using your partner user credentials, go to the source code scanner, create a new source code scan, select the App Exchange listing you have set up for the app, choose the app's package ID, select the version and the scan profile and submit.

Comment: @PhilW, You are suggesting above solution for beta version package? Or Just to confirm you are referring to released version of managed package and We need to connect this released version with dev hub and this dev hub will be  ultimately connected to Partner Business Org.

Comment: As I said before, Checkmarx can be executed on beta release package versions, and this is done exactly the same way as for a release package versions. As outlined above. Your (beta) package's dev hub must **be** the PBO (this is mandated for partners).